# what comes first smtpd milters or cleanup in order of filtering in postfix?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, opendkim, milter

Based on the documentation of the postfix (as stated here: 'https://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_PROXY_README.html') the smtpd milters should be used to filter the emails first and then the cleanup service should be given the email for further processing/filtering. In my case I have used opendkim in smtpd_milter and header_checks (for logging the subjects) in cleanup. I should be getting the output from the opendkim first then he log containing the subject, but it is otherwise (i.e. first subject are logged and then open_dkim output is shown). Below are logs for reference:

```
Dec 14 13:53:10 emg1 postfix/smtpd[27992]: 332DF20248: client=mx-se.comsol.com[176.10.169.229]:34404
Dec 14 13:53:10 emg1 postfix/cleanup[27994]: 332DF20248: warning: header Subject: Guest Webinar: Modeling Electric Machines from mx-se.comsol.com[176.10.169.229]:34404; from=<prvs=171252e791=mail-comsol-in@comsol.co.in> to=<mjn@techfeature.in> proto=ESMTP helo=<mx2-se.comsol.com>

Dec 14 13:53:10 emg1 postfix/cleanup[27994]: 332DF20248: message-id=<20231214082308.5AF2C10A2FAD@se-demail1.comsol.com>

Dec 14 13:53:10 emg1 opendkim[909]: 332DF20248: mx-se.comsol.com [176.10.169.229] not internal

Dec 14 13:53:10 emg1 opendkim[909]: 332DF20248: not authenticated

Dec 14 13:53:10 emg1 opendkim[909]: 332DF20248: DKIM verification successful

Dec 14 13:53:10 emg1 opendkim[909]: 332DF20248: s=comsol d=comsol.co.in a=rsa-sha256 SSL

Dec 14 13:53:10 emg1 opendmarc[858]: 332DF20248: comsol.co.in pass

Dec 14 13:53:10 emg1 postfix/qmgr[27766]: 332DF20248: from=<prvs=171252e791=mail-comsol-in@comsol.co.in>, size=3508, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

Can anyone point out what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In Postfix, the order of filters in the SMTP server (smtpd) process is crucial. As per the provided logs and configuration, it appears that the cleanup service is processing the message before the smtpd milter.

To address this, you should ensure that the smtpd milters are applied before the cleanup service. Here are a few steps to troubleshoot and correct the order:

**Verify Milter Configuration:**

Double-check your Postfix configuration file (typically `/etc/postfix/main.cf`). Ensure that the `smtpd_milters` directive is correctly set to apply milters. It should come before other content filters.

**Check Order of Filters:**

In the same configuration file, look for the `content_filter` or `receive_override_options` directives. Ensure that they are not interfering with the milter order.

Comment: if I mention smtpd_milters after content_filter will they be applied in this sequence? If yes doesn't it changes the whole data flow in postfix.

Comment: The key distinction is that smtpd_milters occurs before the mail is accepted by Postfix, while content_filter occurs after it's been queued.